# Java 7 AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm using the java 7 AsynchronousSocketChannel to write a simple client server app.
Once the connection is made, I start a thread on the server which initializes I/O
streams with:

```
    ObjectInputStream  is;
    ObjectOutputStream os;

    is = new ObjectInputStream( Channels.newInputStream( client ) );
    System.out.println( "Got is" );
    os = new ObjectOutputStream( Channels.newOutputStream( client ) );
    System.out.println( "Got os" );
```

The client uses the same code on its end.

The problem I'm having is that if both initialize the input stream first and then the
output stream, both sides hang. Any of the other 3 combinations works ok, meaning,
both initialize output stream first or one does input and the other does output first.

Anybody have any idea why this might be ?

The client gets a connection with:

```
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress( host, port );
    AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    Future<Void> future = channel.connect( addr );
    future.get();  // blocks till connection is established
```

The server listens with:

```
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress( port );
    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server
        = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind( addr );

    Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> future = server.accept();
    client = future.get( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    if ( client != null ) {
        // open streams as shown above ...
    }
```

Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing, ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream pair exchange hidden service messages. Initialization finishes after the exchange. This means, that when one side opens ObjectOutputStream, the other side has to open ObjectInputStream, and vice versa.

BTW if you use a thread per connection, what is the sense to use AsynchronousSocketChannel , and mot plain socket?

Comment: So how come it works when both sides open the output stream first ?

Comment: Also, when I use the old-style sockets I don't see the problem at all. You're right that I don't need to use async if I'm using a thread per connection (except maybe the newer classes are optimized better); I'm just doing some experiments to see how these classes work together.

Comment: The API docs for the ObjectInputStream shed further light on the matter: _"This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header."_ This explains why initializing **ObjectOutputStream** first on both sides is **not** a problem but initializing **ObjectInputStream** first on both sides **is** a problem.